# Spring Boot - SpEL - Check List Contains - @ConditionalOnExpression

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Given that I have the following properties:

```
values[0]=A
values[1]=B
values[2]=C
```

I need to check that `values` contains A in a `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation. As of yet, I have not found an example of how to do it. I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${values}.contains('A')")
```

It results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 8):

You need  $ expresion surrounded by single quotes

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${values}'.contains('A')")
```

Comment: Not sure it workds: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9274

Comment: This works for comma separated property
source=property,DB
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${source}'.contains('DB')")